# Scrollview does not resize when adding new component in it

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view called `wsview` (whole screen view) inside my scene, covering the whole screen. Inside this view there is a `scrollview` (covering the whole `wsview`). Inside the `scrollview` I have a view (called `viewgod`) and `viewgod` is covering the whole `scrollview`. Inside `viewgod` I have some components (one under the other and each of them has constraints to the top and bottom component). Now I am trying to interleave another component (another view, called `myview`) between these components of `viewgod`.

When I add it, the scene does not resize in a way that `myview` will fit there the way I want; it overlaps with the other components. I defined the constraints so that I have top and bottom spacing to the components it is interleaved, but that does not solve the problem. I have also tried to resize the `viewgod`/`wsview`, but I can't resize them. I have also tried to resize the whole scene, and that kind of works, but I have to move the underlying components by hand and all of the constraints get messed up.

Is there a smarter way to do it or is there any way to do it at all?
[storyboard ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaD7M.png)

Comment: are you using autolayout

Comment: Show us the design and code please!

Comment: show your storyboard ss. and code what u tried.

Comment: @RahulGUsai Sorry for my late answer. The existing design was not made by me, it was made by a more experienced developer, so i think he did use autolayout.

Comment: can you post the image of storyboard

Comment: @iPeter Sorry for the late answer, i didn't write any code for this part, i thought i can only arrange it in interface builder.

Comment: @MRizwan33 i just uploaded a picture with the storyboard

Comment: @RahulGUsai i just posted it

Comment: the red rectangle is what i tried to insert

Comment: I kind of did it, by dragging all of the other components by hand, but i will have to insert more components and i think that will be very painful and time consuming and it just doesn't seem the right way to do it

Comment: make sure last view have constraint to view in scrollview

Comment: @RahulGUsai you mean myview as last view? i put the center contraints for myview to view in scrollview and top & bottom to the components on top and underneath of it

Comment: @walexc - you commented *"i didn't write any code for this part, i thought i can only arrange it in interface builder"* ... do you mean you are trying to add `myview` in your storyboard layout? Or are you trying to "dynamically" add `myview` while the app is running?

Comment: @DonMag add myview in my storyboard layout

Comment: OK - *before* trying to insert your new view, is the layout correct? No red warnings about conflicting constraints?

Comment: @DonMag nope, everything is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "insert" a view between other views, while maintaining the rest of the layout, you need to delete the Vertical Spacing constraint between the "above" and "below" views, give yourself a little space, add your new view, then add vertical spacing constraints from the "above" view to the new view, and from the new view to the "below" view.

Hopefully, this will make sense:

Imagine your entire layout like this:

[image]

and you want to insert a new view between `B` and `C`.

Delete the constraint from `B` to `C`:

[image]

[image]

Select all the views from `C` to the bottom, and move them down to give yourself some space to work:

[image]

Now add your "new view", and move it / size it into position:

[image]

Re-adjust the position of the views below it:

[image]

and, finally, add new vertical spacing constraints from `B` to `NewView` and from `NewView` to `C`:

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought that there may be some way to automatically obtain this functionality.

Comment: Well, another option is to use a `UIStackView`. That way, the only positioning constraints needed are on the stack view itself. Then you can insert a new view into the stack view and everything shifts down automatically.